# how to solve variable in continous function and prove it is differentialable with a function include sinx

Tags: calculus, limits

Assuming, $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-9}{x^2+2x-3},\;\;\;\text{if}\;\;x<-3$$ and 
$$f(x)=a\sin(\pi x)+b,\;\;\;\text{if}\;\; x\geq-3$$
$a$ and $b$ are some constants.
find $a$ and $b$ if $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere
I use left limit =right limit to compute it
I find that $$a\sin(-3\pi)+b =3/2$$
but it is the final ans?? how can I solve $a$ and $b$ 
also, the question also ask me :are any $a$ and $b$ can make $f(x)$ differentiable everywhere?
how can I prove it is correct or incorrext, I have no idea about this.

Comment: Your approach -- equating limits -- is correct, but there is something missing in your question. Where did $b$ come from?

Comment: the question said that a and b ar e some constant

Comment: There is not $b$ in the definition of $f$.

Comment: sorry  i miss it

Comment: To find $a$ and $b$, evaluate $f$ at some points.

Comment: Hint: First adjust `b` to make `f` continuous at `-3` (you nearly completed this step, already), then adjust `a` to make `f` differentiable there.

Comment: so$$ a=-1/2pi$$??

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable at $x=-3$, then the left-sided derivative and right-sided derivative are equal. Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to +0}\frac{f(-3+h)-f(-3)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to+0}\frac{a\sin(\pi (-3+h))-a\sin(-3\pi)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to +0}\frac{a(\sin(h\pi)\cos(3\pi) -\cos(h\pi)\sin(3\pi)+\sin (3\pi))}{h}\\
&=-a\pi
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to -0}\frac{f(-3+h)-f(-3)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to -0}\frac{\frac{h-6}{h-4}-\frac{3}{2}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to-0}\frac{2h-12-3h+12}{2h(h-4)}\\
&=\lim_{h\to-0}\frac{1}{2(4-h)}\\
&=\frac{1}{8}.
\end{align}
Therefore, we get $a=-\dfrac{1}{8\pi}$ and $b=\dfrac{3}{2}$.